# Accessing a selected value instead of key in drupal 8

Tags: forms

I need to access values instead of keys from a custom form select field. To get the keys, I am using `$form_state->getValue()` but I don't know how to access the values. Kindly help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that code is in a submit/validate method, you have the original form array available, so you can grab the options straight from the element definition:

```
$key = $form_state->getValue('foo');
$val = $form['foo']['#options'][$key];
```